# Need help with $e^x=1/x$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I've tried everything. I expressed $x$ and I got $x=\ln{1\over x}$, and don't know what to do. Original question is to find $e^x-{1\over x}=0$. There is a solution I've typed it in Wolfram

Comment: There is no closed solution for this equation. Only numerical methods can be applied.

Comment: I use this to derivate f(x)=e^x-lnx, how to find maximum there?

Comment: This is the [$\Omega$ constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no closed solution**. However note that:

$$e^x = \frac{1}{x}$$

has one real root. To see this you can consider it as a function , differentiate , determine the range etc. Therefore we have a root.

This root is a famous constant denoted as $\Omega$. Its approximate value is $0.5671$.

Otherwise, this root can be expressed via Lambert W.That is if $r$ denotes the root then we have $r=W(1)$.

**P.S** There exists an integral represantation of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2):

This can be rewritten as

$$ xe^x = 1$$

And here, there is no "simple" answer, you need to introduce the 
[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications).